# How to validate gender in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html

```
<p><span>Male</span> <input type="radio" class="gender" value="male">
         <span>Female</span> <input type="radio"  class="gender" value="female" >
        <div id="dis"></div>
        </p>
```

and this is jquery code

```
var gender = $('.gender').val();
    if ($(".gender:checked").length > 1 || $(".gender:checked").length == 0){
      $('#dis').slideDown().html('<span id="error">Please choose a gender</span>');
    }
    else{
      alert(gender)
    }
```

Comment: <span>Male</span> <input type="radio" class="gender" value="male">
    <span>Female</span> <input type="radio"  class="gender" value="female" >
   <div id="dis"></div>

Comment: @nick thi is html code...

Comment: give the radio inputs names and instead use a selector of `input[name="gender"]::checked` or just set a default of checked to one of the two to verify that they will always be either male or female.

Comment: You should consider getting a HBT certification. That gender list looks like something from a dreadful history book.

Comment: @Shehzad Ahmed: What validation you indeed for gender. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/pcsk195t/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
   <p>
           <span>Male</span> <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="male">
           <span>Female</span> <input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="female">
           <div id="dis"></div>
   </p>
```

Javascript:

```
   if($('.gender').val() == "") 
       alert('Select');
```

Comment: if user select male female both..?

Comment: @ShehzadAhmed Generally radio buttons work so that you can't choose two options. Add an identical `name` attribute to the radio buttons and it'll automatically prevent choosing two.

Comment: If you're using the attribute name, then you won't have this issue.

Comment: use name attribute <p><span>Male</span> <input type="radio" name="gender" class="gender" value="male">
         <span>Female</span> <input name="gender" type="radio"  class="gender" value="female" >

Answer (score 0):

you mean you need to choose the gender when you change the radio button. if yes here is the code

```js
$( ".gender" ).change(function() {
  alert( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>Male</span> <input type="radio" class="gender" value="male">
         <span>Female</span> <input type="radio"  class="gender" value="female" >
        <div id="dis"></div>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hope this is what you want!!

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            }
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Please select your gender.</h4>
    <p> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Get Value"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should the attribute `name` on both `INPUT` tags with the same value.